# Please change to nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, combobox, nested, range, cell

I have edited my post for formatting error.
Thank you for feedback.

Now I am using lot of 'For Each' to find the range.
I am searching the matching combobox value first vertically(Column( and then horizondaly(rows)
Then going to the particular range.

Is there any way to find the cell which carries my combobox value using loop and then select the range.?

Thank you.
NB:- Please don't laugh if you feel my program as a comic. because i learned all this from googling.

```
'Cancel Button`
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload UserForm1
End Sub`

'Goto range selection3
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error Resume Next
If ComboBox3.Value = "Select" Then
MsgBox "Please Select a Seller"
Else
Call Show_Page
Unload UserForm1`
End If
End Sub

'select page
Sub Show_Page()

For Each cell In Range("A2:A10")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
Worksheets("p1").Activate
Call Show_Range
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Range("B2:B10")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
Worksheets("p2").Activate
Call Show_Range
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Range("C2:C10")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
Worksheets("p3").Activate
Call Show_Range
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Range("D2:D10")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
Worksheets("p4").Activate
Call Show_Range
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Range("E2:E10")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
Worksheets("p5").Activate
Call Show_Range
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

End Sub

Sub Show_Range()

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A2:E2")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:j106").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A3:E3")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A111:j216").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A4:E4")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A221:j326").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A5:E5")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A331:j436").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A6:E6")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A441:j546").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A7:E7")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A551:j656").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A8:E8")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A661:j766").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A9:E9")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A771:j876").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("home").Range("A10:E10")
If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A881:j986").Select
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The above probably will not run.  It is missing a SUB and a NEXT.  It appears that you have edited/arranged the original code, perhaps added blank lines,  and perhaps left out some lines.  Could you paste the original code?

Comment: Sir, thank you for reply. I have edited my post. please have a look.  Now I am using lot of 'For Each' to find the range.
I am searching the matching combobox value first vertically(Column) and then horizondaly(rows)
Then going to the particular range.

Is there any way to find the cell which carries my combobox value using loop and then select the range.?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you want.  The SheetNames are an array, and the RangeStrings are also an array, to allow them to be changed at a later time.  (note:the Arrays are zero based, and thus we skip the zero-eth item)

Mainly, go thru the cells in the Key area only once.  Then use the column location of the found cell to determine the proper SheetName to activate, and the row location of the found cell to determine the proper RangeString to select.  This exits when first match is found.  (I don't understand your original Exit For followed by Exit Sub --> what do you expect to happen?  Can more than one page be "selected"?)

```
'select page
Sub Show_Page()

    ' look only once at all cells in the key area
    For Each aCell In Sheets("home").Range("A2:E10")

        If aCell.Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then  '>> OOps, my test only Sheets("home").Cells(1, "A") Then
            Dim sheetNamesArray() As Variant, sheetIndex As Long, theSheet As String
            sheetNamesArray = Array("zero", "offset1", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5")
            sheetIndex = aCell.Column   ' numeric value equivalent of "A", ... "E"
            theSheet = sheetNamesArray(sheetIndex)
            Worksheets(theSheet).Activate

            Dim sheetRangesArray() As Variant, rangeIndex As Long, rangeString As String
            sheetRangesArray = Array("zero", "notRow1", "A001;J106", "A111;J216", "A221;J326", "A331;J436", "A441;J546", "A551;J656", "A661;J766", "A771;J876", "A881;J986")
            rangeIndex = aCell.Row      ' numeric value 2...10
            rangeString = sheetRangesArray(rangeIndex)

            ActiveSheet.Range(rangeString).Select

            Exit Sub    ' once we have found it, exit the SUB (and implicitly also the FOR)
        End If

    Next aCell

End Sub

'eliminate Show_Range()
```

Comment: Thank you for your great support...I replaced my program with Sub Show_Page. Unfortunately it's not working. No error shown. I thank I failed to connect it with ComboBox3. Whether I have to do any modifications on that.. waiting for your reply...thank you again.

Comment: Revised to use ComboBox3 (I had been testing with Sheets("home").Cells(1, "A") )

Comment: No sir. It's not working...I ll check one more time and let you know.

Comment: I can't follow the condition given to the second part to find particular range. please give a reply.

Comment: Sir, it is not working and no errors shown. i can't follow the condition given in second part. whether i have to give one more loop to find range. please reply.